# Cakephp 2.4.5 Custom HTML in baked views

Tags: html, cakephp, themes, view

I have been reviewing documentation in the cookbook to generate custom HTML in baked views and I'm having difficulty in getting my custom code to run during the bake process.

I followed the instructions as stated which are:

Modify default HTML produced by “baked” templates¶

If you wish to modify the default HTML output produced by the “bake” command, follow these simple steps as outline at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html

For baking custom views

1. Go into: `lib/Cake/Console/Templates/default/views`
2. Notice the 4 files there
3. Copy them to your: app/Console/Templates/[themename]/views
4. Make changes to the HTML output to control the way “bake” builds your views

The [themename] path segment should be the name of the bake theme that you are creating. Bake theme names need to be unique, so don’t use ‘default’.

For my "theme" I chose the name dalma and placed my modified versions of the view generation code in

`app/Console/Templates/dalma/views/`

and then rebaked a specific table and none of my changes appeared.

I had assumed that I would be prompted for a theme when I ran the bake from the CLI which was not the case.

I then found instructions which talk about assigning a theme in the AppController which I did and this did not help.

Next I found another article http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/22/cake-bake-custom-templates/ that talked about placing the custom code in the app/vendors/shells/dalma/ directory and this did not work

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Didnt you read the bottom part of that linked post (which is mainly 1.x)? "Update 2012-02-26" where it tells you where to put them in Cake2.x? There is also a fully working example (as a plugin) linked there.

Comment: what did you name the files inside of `app/Console/Templates/dalma/views/`

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a layout specified in your appController that matches the folder name in Console/Templates

appController.php

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->layout = 'bootstrap';
}
```

Console/Templates/bootstrap has my bake template.

With this setup the bake console prompts me for a template choice. (there may be other ways to specify this)

Here is my custom bake template which should help. (this is a forked work and not all my original code)
https://github.com/arco000/BootstrapCake